# Non-generic interface as a synonym for generic one

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have one generic interface in c#, and almost always I use it with one of the types. I want to create a non-generic interface for that type and use it.

Let's say, I've the following code:

```
public interface IMyGenericList<out T> where T : IItem
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetList();
}

public class MyList<T> : IMyGenericList<T> where T : IItem
{
    public IEnumerable<T> GetList()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

it works well. Most times I need `IMyGenericList<IItem>`, so i try the following:

```
public interface IMyItemsList : IMyGenericList<IItem>
{
}
```

but I can't make MyList implement IMyItemsList for some reason. The following code returns an error

```
public class MyList<T> : IMyItemsList, IMyGenericList<T> where T : IItem
{
    public IEnumerable<T> GetList()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

saying that `IEnumerable<IItem> is not implemented`.

Why is it so/what can I do with this? 
Thanks.

Ok, thanks to your answers I figured out it's impossible to do it exactly as I wanted initially. I will post another question on why this is impossible :)
Here it is: [One function implementing Generic and non-generic interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049702/one-function-implementing-generic-and-non-generic-interface)

Comment: Where is your `GetEnumerator` method?

Comment: I'm not implementing IEnumerable, I just return a value with that type

Comment: "Most times I need `IMyGenericList<IItem>`". You can only ever have this due to your type constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specific example wouldn't work, as your class:

```
public class MyList<T> : IMyItemsList, IMyGenericList<T> where T : IItem
{
  public IEnumerable<T> GetList()
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

is trying to implement both a `IEnumerable<IItem> GetList()` and an `IEnumerable<T> GetList()`, which are two different things.  This first is explicitly an enumerable of `IItem` (as required by your `IMyItemsList` interface), and the second is an enumerable of `T`.

In this scenario `T` is of type `IItem` but is not explicitly `IItem`.  Therefore at compile time, the `IEnumerable<IItem> GetList()` is not `IEnumerable<T> GetList()` so the compiler will correctly throw an error telling you that `IEnumerable<IItem> GetList()` is not implemented.

The other problem you will run into, is what happens when somebody does:

```
var list = new MyList<IItem>();
```

The compiler will try and create an a concrete implementation of `MyList<IItem>` which will have two definitions of `IEnumerable<IItem> GetList()`.

I would reconsider your design to evaluate a singular `IEnumerable<T> GetList()`.

Also, and just picky on my part: "enumerable" != "list" :P

Comment: imho, IEnumerable<T> where T : IItem can be always casted to IEnumerable<IItem>, isn't it? I thought, it's what covariance is for in .net? I agree with you, that it looks ugly and will cause problems to have a separate explicit IEnumerable<IItem> GetList() implementation

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have your `IMyItemsList` interface inherited from `IMyGenericList<out T>` interface if you want to have `MyList<T>` implementing both of them. But you can modify your IMyItemsList interface as defined below:

```
public interface IItem
{
}

public interface IMyItemsList
{
    IEnumerable<IItem> GetList();
}

public interface IMyGenericList<out T> where T : IItem
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetList();
}

public class MyList<T> : IMyGenericList<T>, IMyItemsList 
    where T : IItem
{
    public IEnumerable<T> GetList()
    {
        return null;
    }

    IEnumerable<IItem> IMyItemsList.GetList()
    {
        return this.GetList().Cast<IItem>();
    }
}
```