# One function implementing Generic and non-generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Lets say I have a class, which implements a generic interface
    public interface IItem {}

```
public interface IStuff<out TItem> where TItem : IItem
{
    TItem FavoriteItem { get; }
}

public class MyStuff<TItem> : IStuff<TItem> where TItem : IItem
{
    public TItem FavoriteItem
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

I have also one non-generic interface

```
public interface IFavoriteItem
{
    IItem FavoriteItem { get; }
}
```

I'd like to make MyStuff class implement this IFavoriteItem interface. Since TItem implements IItem it seems for me, that `public TItem FavoriteItem` property is implementing IFavoriteItem already.

But compiler doesn't think so, and it wants me to declare a separate `IItem IFavoriteItem.FavoriteItem` in MyClass. Why is it so? Isn't c# covariance the thing that should play here and solve my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that `FavoriteItem` of `IFavoriteItem` may not **be** `IItem`, where on the `IFavoriteItem`, it **must** be an `IItem`. The only way to solve this is by:

```
IItem IFavoriteItem.FavoriteItem
{
    get { return FavoriteItem; }
}
```

This will simply shortcut the call to your `TItem` implementation.

A good example of where this is used quite often is with the implementation of `IEnumerable<>`. These often look like this:

```
public class MyEnumerable : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: How it may not be `IItem`, if i explicitly specified `where TItem : IItem`?

Comment: Because it can be an inherited interface of, or a `class` implementation of `IItem`. The `where` does not specify that it must be **exactly** `IItem`, but instead that it must be `typeof(IItem).IsAssignableFrom()`. However, your `IFavoriteItem` has the exact `IItem` type specified.

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but why is it that List<T> implements both IList<T> and IList, but doesn't have to implement Add(object item), it only implements Add(T item) ?

Comment: Nevermind, found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388782/how-listt-does-not-implement-addobject-value