# how List<T> does not implement Add(object value)?

Tags: c#, interface, c#-2.0, explicit-interface

I believe it's pretty stupid, and I am a bit embarrassed to ask this kind of question, but I still could not find the answer:

I am looking at the class `List<T>` , which implemetns `IList`.

```
public class List<T> : IList
```

one of the methods included in Ilist is

```
int Add(object value)
```

I understand that `List<T>` should not expose that method (type safety...), and it really does not. But how can it be? mustnt class implement the entire interface?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by not exposing it, interfaces can only have public members.

Comment: @Brad: `List<T>` is not an interface, and he's saying that `List<T>` should not expose it.

Comment: It is called "Explicit interface implementation".

Comment: Ahh, coffee deprivation; I understand the question now, it's what happens when you skim between sips. Also why I posted a comment not an answer. ;p

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that this (interface) method is [implemented explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
public class List<T> : IList
{
     int IList.Add( object value ) {this.Add((T)value);}
}
```

By doing so, the `Add( object )` method will by hidden.  You'll only able to call it, if you cast the `List<T>` instance back to an `IList` instance.

Comment: You're right about the explicit implementation. But you should fix your example ("recursion" and "can't compile" keep popping up in my mind)... :)

Answer (score 3):

A quick trip to reflector shows that IList.Add is implemented like this:

```
int IList.Add(object item)
{
    ThrowHelper.IfNullAndNullsAreIllegalThenThrow<T>(item, ExceptionArgument.item);
    try
    {
        this.Add((T) item);
    }
    catch (InvalidCastException)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowWrongValueTypeArgumentException(item, typeof(T));
    }
    return (this.Count - 1);
}
```

In other words, the implementation casts it to *T* to make it work and fails it you pass a non *T* compatible type in.

Comment: The information is correct, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Sure it does. IList.Add does a cast and calls the IList<T>.Add implementation.

Answer (score 2):

`List<T>` explicitly implements `IList.Add(object value)` which is why it's not typically visible. You can test by doing the following:

```
IList list = new List<string>();
list.Add(new SqlDataReader()); // valid at compile time, will fail at runtime
```

Answer (score 1):

It implements it explicitly, so you have to cast to `IList` first to use it.

```
List<int> l = new List<int>();
IList il = (IList)l;
il.Add(something);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call it be casting your list instance to the interface first:

```
List<int> lst = new List<int>();
((IList)lst).Add("banana");
```

And you'll get as nice, runtime, ArgumentException.

Answer (score 1):

[Frederik is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388782/how-listt-does-not-implement-addobject-value/4388798#4388798) that `List<T>`'s implementation of `IList` is explicit for certain members, particularly those that pose a threat to type safety.

The implementation he suggests in his answer can't be right, of course, since it wouldn't compile.

In cases like this, the typical approach is to make a valiant effort to *try* to get the interface member to work, but to give up if it's impossible.

Note that the [`IList.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.add.aspx) method is defined to return:

> The position into which the new
>   element was inserted, or -1 to
>   indicate that the item was not
>   inserted into the collection.

So in fact, a full implementation *is* possible:

```
int IList.Add(object value)
{
    if (value is T)
    {
        Add((T)value);
        return Count - 1;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

This is just a guess, of course. (If you really want to know for sure, you can always use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).) It may be slightly different; for example it could throw a `NotSupportedException`, which is often done for incomplete interface implementations such as [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx)'s implementation of `IList<T>`. But since the above meets the documented requirements of `IList.Add`, I suspect it's close to the real thing.

Comment: The actual implementation (at least in .NET4) throws an `ArgumentException` if you attempt to add an item of the wrong type. (And, if I recall correctly, there was a small bug prior to .NET4 where trying to add `null` to a `List<Nullable<T>>` via `IList.Add` would also erroneously throw the exception.)